# Pushing incremental data to cloud using PhoneGap

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, afnetworking, cloud-hosting

I seem to be getting confused over the myriad options available in mobile frameworks and cloud storage today. I have previously written a few relatively simple, native iPhone apps and I've been programming in Java and C++ for some time.

I now face the problem of writing an app across multiple mobile platforms and I'm scoping out technologies at the moment.

The app is heavily data-driven and will store data in the cloud.  Data will be manipulated on the device. My problem is not finding a mobile framework and cloud provider to do the job, but the fact that there are so many!

Something like AFIncrementalStore (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore) with Heroku seems like it would be exactly what I would need if writing a native iPhone app.  (There's a good example video of it on mobile.heroku.com at the moment.)  But is there anything like this when using PhoneGap? Performance aside, PhoneGap seems to be my best option for rapidly writing an app across iOS and Android (my initial two platforms.)

I hope this question isn't too vague. If it is, it shows my level of confusion...